# Test iptables from localhost

Tags: linux, kernel, iptables, tcp

I have a Linux system with two interfaces lo and eth0, I have some iptables rules which will block some tcp ports.

It's possible to teste my own firewall rules by implementing a probing service to port scan my own ports? the idea is to port scan my external interface eth0 but doing that inside.

I have made some basic implementations in C++ with raw sockets, but in the end the packet is always going to lo interface I don't see anything on the eth0.

Seems the kernel is doing the shorcut because the destination is equal to the source address, any thought ideas on this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [network](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages/network_namespaces.7) [namespace](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages/namespaces.7), and link it to your system with a pair of [*veth*](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2018/10/22/introduction-to-linux-interfaces-for-virtual-networking/#veth) interfaces. That way you'll really have two network stacks: the host's and the additional network namespace's. This will very cheaply (way more than a VM, only the network is separated) create an host to scan from. The easiest command to manage this is [`ip netns`](https://manpages.debian.org/iproute2/ip-netns.8) (which is designed to keep network namespaces up by mounting a reference to them even when no process is using them):

```
ip netns add scanner
ip link add name veth0 type veth peer netns scanner name veth0
ip address add 192.0.2.2/24 dev veth0
ip -n scanner address add 192.0.2.3/24 dev veth0
ip link set veth0 up
ip -n scanner link set lo up #not really needed, but can avoid a few surprising results
ip -n scanner link set veth0 up
ip netns exec scanner /path/to/my/probing_service ...
```

You now can scan 192.0.2.2 from 192.0.2.3, and this won't use *lo*. Of course it all depends on your firewall rules (you'd have to adapt IPs, interface names, both or a few other things).

Comment: yes I already tried that and it's working on a normal ubuntu machine, the problem on my use case is that my kernel version don't support the veth driver. thanks

Comment: veth has been available since [around kernel 2.6.23](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/drivers/net/Kconfig?id=e314dbdc1c0dc6a548ecf0afce28ecfd538ff568), is your kernel older?

Comment: No it's 4.18.16 but I'm compiling a new kernel with Virtual ethernet pair enable, I have a question in my use case I want to scan only the eth0 interface, it's possible to scan eth0 from separate netowork namespace and the packet is acepted by the stack as a normal incoming packet?

Comment: As I told you have to change something: either the rules to match the network used for test, or you can also match the testing network to match the rules: you can rename the physical interface to move it away, name the veth interface eth0, put all the address and routing configuration on this eth0 interface. That way you can test the firewall rules without changing them. There are other ways possible, but in any way you have to change something somewhere to do the test. Else just use a separate physical host.

Comment: Yes thank you for your suggestion, but I already tried everything from the veth0 to the physicall interface, seems to be almost impossible to treat a packt as an incoming packet.

Comment: If the answer isn't a solution you can remove the "accepted answer" tag. That's fine by me.